# Where would I put -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { }?

Tags: objective-c, webview, uiwebview

If I put this in the .m file, how would I link it to my webView? It does nothing when the webView loads.

Comment: Time to learn about delegates: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Answer (score 1):

You implement this method on the class of the object that acts as the webView's delegate.

If you have a viewController that contains the webView you will often want that viewController to be the delegate and this is hooked up like so (potentially in viewDidLoad):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.webView.delegate = self;
}
```

If you added the webView in interface builder you could avoid this delegate set up in code and drag the appropriate connections from the webView to the file's owner